# Not able to call instance method

Tags: objective-c, ios5

```
+(DetailViewController *) instance{
    return (DetailViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
}

-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [[DetailViewController instance]showViewInFullScreen:self withModel:self.messageModel];
}
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
-(void)showViewInFullScreen:(UIViewExtention*)viewToShow withModel:(MessageModel*)model{
    [viewController showViewInFullScreen:viewToShow withModel:model];
}
```

When i am reaching to the tapped method not able to make call to showViewInFullScreen which is in DetailViewController class.And app is terminating with the following message.

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>
> '-[AppDelegate showViewInFullScreen:withModel:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting your app delegate to the DetailViewController class?

If you want to create a singleton of the DetailViewController class you need to do something like this (assuming you are using ARC):

```
+(DetailViewController *) instance{
    // Create a singleton instance of the class
    static DetailViewController *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hesham,yes using ARC. reaching to the showViewInFullScreen in DetailViewController.m class.But[viewController showViewInFullScreen:viewToShow withModel:model]; This line of code should make call to the method showViewInFullScreen which is in WallViewController.m file .Instead of reaching to this file ,my code is going back to the -(void)tapped: method.Could you please suggest what i need to check